# How to control order of the tabs in the template selection of SharePoint site creation page?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

The *New SharePoint Site* page has a *Template Selection* section which can contains multiple tabs. For example, *Meetings* and *Collaboration*. These are controlled in webtemp.xml using *DisplayCategory*.  While hiding and unhiding different OOTB templates, I somehow ended up switching the order of the tabs so that *Meetings* show up first. Can't seem to find any references on how to control the order of the tabs and make *Collaboration* first again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has webtemp.xml been reordered or edited so that Team Site, Blank Site, and Document Workspace are now either below the Meetings sites or are marked as hidden? I captured the output of GetAvailableWebTemplates for a test Team Site and the first 12 templates match the contents and order of an OOTB webtemp.xml. If any of those Collaboration templates are visible in your list, try moving it above the Meeting templates, save, and recycle the app pool.

Comment: Yes, all the collaboration templates which appeared above the meetings ones were set to hidden=true. Moving the meeting ones all the way to the bottom fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Publishing Site? If so, check Site Settings > Page Layout and Site Template Settings to see if any Site Templates are being restricted. From what I can tell in Reflector, the [TemplatePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.templatepicker.aspx) control calls [SPWeb.GetAvailableWebTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466366.aspx), which should consistently return OOTB templates first followed by any custom templates. TemplatePicker then loops through the templates and creates a tab each time it encounters a new [SPWebTemplate.DisplayCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebtemplate.displaycategory.aspx).

Comment: Not a publishing site. When creating a subsite, the only two tabs I have showing are Meetings and Collaboration. I just need to have Collaboration show first.

Comment: I created a new answer (and removed the original comment) since the original answer might be helpful in the future for someone with a Publishing site. Thanks.